# error in below code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two procedures   PROC1  and PROC2 .
PROC2   is loading data using external tables concept into a table. 
BAD ,LOG and DISCARD file is generated in server

PROC1 is calling PROC2 , then again  it returns to PROC1   for  checking that if BAD/LOG/ DISCARD file is generated in the server .

```
create or replace PROC1  

as 
v_result_bad  number ;
v_result_dsc  number ;
v_directory_name varchar2(50) := 'xyz';
v_badfile varchar2(50) := 'ABC.bad';
v_discard varchar2(50) := 'ABC.dsc';

begin

----call the procedure to load data and generate bad/log/discard file

PROC2('abc.txt');

---------check for bad and discard file existence
v_result_bad := FILE_EXISTS(v_directory_name,v_badfile);
dbms_output.put_line(v_result_bad);

v_result_dsc := FILE_EXISTS(v_directory_name,v_discard);
dbms_output.put_line(v_result_dsc);

end PROC1;

----------------------------

create or replace PROC2 (file_name in  varchar2)as
v_discard varchar2(100):= 'ABC.dsc';
v_badfile varchar2(100):= 'ABC.bad';
v_logfile varchar2(100):= 'ABC.log';

begin

execute immediate 'create table ext_tab_aci(
empid number,
emp_name varchar2(50),
dept  varchar2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY xyz
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    discardfile IMPORT_GDE:'''||v_discard||'''
    BADFILE IMPORT_GDE:'''||v_badfile||'''
    LOGFILE IMPORT_GDE:'''||v_logfile||'''
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '''||','||'''  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '''||'"'||'''
    (empid,
     emp_name,
     dept
      )
    )
    LOCATION  ('''||file_name||''')
    )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

end PROC2;
```

after loading the data in PROC2 , when it comes back to PROC1 then its checking if bad/discard file is generated or not.

value of "v_result_bad  and v_result_dsc"  is coming as 0 i.e when it comes back to PROC1 till then BAD/DISCARD is not generated.
these files are generating after it proc1 is checking the presence of file
so can any one tell me  what need to be done to so that v_result_bad and v_result_bad value is 1.what alterations i need to make in proc1

"v_result_bad and v_result_bad " variable will be equal to 1 when file exist else 0. these variable should return 1.

Comment: do these files actually exist?

Comment: The above code won't compile. In PROC1 there's no definition of  `v_directory_name`, `v_badfile`, and `v_discard`. In PROC2 the `execute immediate` which creates the external table isn't terminated by a semicolon. Please edit your question and post code which you have actually compiled. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyC.      YES it exists . its getting generated  after PROC2 pocedure returns to PROC1  and checks the existence of file . while its checks the existence .its not there in server so  it returns 0, but  that only it gets generated

Comment: I only see you trying to import files, I don't see anywhere you are actually creating files, look at this article about creating and writing to files in pl/sql: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003404

Comment: @JeremyC In Proc2  file which is getting loaded and   has any discrepency then BAD and DISCARD file will be genereated in the server,I want to read that  BAD and DISCARD file .